# c_str() ing a string - all other lines than the first line are lost

Tags: c++, c, string

I have a stringstream, which contains multiple lines of text.

For example,

```
f.html                            Sat Oct 19 22:59:47 2013         23675
folder                            Mon Nov  4 19:36:14 2013         4096
readdirpractice.cpp               Tue Nov  5 03:00:10 2013         1203
server.cpp                        Mon Nov  4 21:22:27 2013         11369
photo.jpg                         Wed Oct 23 01:45:04 2013         4360
qq                                Sun Nov  3 01:54:36 2013         66031
server.cpp~                       Mon Nov  4 21:22:25 2013         11368
myhttp.cpp                        Sun Nov  3 01:43:09 2013         1816
getoptpractice.cpp~               Sun Nov  3 01:15:25 2013         1324
```

This is what the stringstream typically looks like.

When I converted this stringstream to string, the information was the same.

However, when I converted this to a C string, it only takes the first line, and all other lines are lost.

It only has

```
f.html                            Sat Oct 19 22:59:47 2013         23675
```

after the conversion.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

I attach some portion of my code.

```
if(is_dir) {
    char dirname[1024];
    strncpy(dirname, requests[1].c_str(), sizeof(dirname));
    dirname[sizeof(dirname)-1] = 0;

    DIR           *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir(dirname);
    stringstream ss;
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            char* file = dir->d_name;
            if(file[0] != '.') {
                struct stat sb;

                if (stat(file, &sb) == -1) {
                    cerr << "stat error" << endl;
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }

                char* lm = ctime(&sb.st_mtime);
                string lastmod(lm);
                lastmod.at(lastmod.size()-1) = '\0';
                string spacing = "                                  ";
                ss << file << spacing.substr(0, spacing.size() - strlen(file)) << lastmod << spacing.substr(0, spacing.size() - lastmod.size()) << sb.st_size << '\n';
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    //cout << ss.str() << endl; // for testing
    char msg2[10000];
    strncpy(msg2, ss.str().c_str(), sizeof(msg2));
    msg2[sizeof(msg2)-1] = 0;
    msg = msg2;
```

Comment: @kfsone `stream << std::endl` is equivalent to `stream << '\n' << std::flush`. Why should OP use `std::endl`?

Comment: What is "msg"? What's the purpose of "msg2"? Is msg a std::string? If so, get rid of msg2 and use `msg.assign(ss.str().c_str(), std::min(ss.str().size(), 10000);`

Comment: `endl` performs a flush which is usually unnecessary. Used on a file it forces a system (kernel) call. This is not a good practice.

Comment: msg is defined above the `if(is_dir)`, as `char *msg`. It is the return value.

Comment: "It is the return value" No. its **undefined behavior**. If this is a function returning the address in `msg`, you're returning the address of a char buffer (`msg2`) that is about to disappear.

Comment: Yes, the endl vs '\n' was intended to have a question mark at the end. That's why it was a comment not an answer ;-P

Comment: @WhozCraig How can I use `msg` in my code to replace `msg2`? Can I directly pass `msg` without allocating spaces?(i.e., without `msg2[10000]` part)

Comment: @user2418202 Send it in as a parameter to your function. Make the *caller* give you the address of the return buffer as well as the size. The only other options are static (yuck) or dynamic (doable, but the caller has to free it later). Ok. a global would admittedly work as well, but that's even uglier than a static.

Comment: Can I do something like msg = char[10000]?

Comment: Just figured out I couldn't, but something similar?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot have the ***caller*** pass an appropriately sized buffer as a parameter. I.e. `void myFunc(char result[], size_t maxlen)` and use that buffer and size info as your target? Honestly, I would probably go with a `malloc()`ed solution for this specific instance only because the content can be so dynamic. As I think about it, a caller buffer may not be big enough, and you're left with little choice but informing them via return value as such. What you do is your choice, but what you're doing *now* is not the right solution.

Comment: The reason is that there is `else` part that is more complicated. I dynamically allocated spaces for it in `else` part(I copied some example code). Is it discouraged too?

Comment: Rather than allocating dynamic memory, why not use a class that encapsulates dynamic string memory, such as `std::string`. Make your function take a `std::string& msg` so that the caller has to supply a std::string, and then all your function has to do is populate it. (see example in my answer)

Comment: @kfsone One reason would be this is a C-interface function implemented in a C++ library, called from C code, but I concur, ideally just returning a `std::string` is the *best* solution.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's true but he's already using sstream in the code, switching to string would help him minimize the contact-surface with C-strings.

Comment: @kfsone maybe I didn't say that right. He can certainly do whatever he wants within the body of this thing. The point I was making was simply that there are reasons the access-interface into this function may well *not* be allowed to have C++'isms. What happens in Vegas can certainly stay in Vegas, but the mode to get there and back is a different issue, and may be one reason why the OP's is doing it this way.

Comment: @WhozCraig Understood - there's probably a missing "instead" in my earlier comment. I'm not one of the 'that looks like C!' witch hunters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::string` probably has embedded `'\0'` (NUL) characters which prematurely terminate the `char` sequence when it is interpreted as a C string.

Try erasing NUL bytes using [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Edit - this could be your problem:

```
             lastmod.at(lastmod.size()-1) = '\0';
```

This is just asking for trouble. `std::string` faithfully stored your NUL byte and copied it into the output.

Comment: +1 and @user2418202 take heed to my comment in general-comments above. If you think it "works" by fixing this, yet you're returning a pointer to a local buffer in a function, think again.

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig, I will do so.

Comment: But I cannot think of how I am going to do what you say. I will definitely spend some time later, but it does not sound so simple

Comment: @user2418202 It is. its just a little more work. May seem like a lot if you aren't familiar with how, but like all things it gets easier with practice.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, you indicated that "msg" is the return value.

```
char msg2[10000];
strncpy(msg2, ss.str().c_str(), sizeof(msg2));
msg2[sizeof(msg2)-1] = 0;
msg = msg2;
```

"msg2" is being created as a local variable, i.e. on the stack. You are then copying your stringstream into this stack area, taking the address of the string (on the stack) and then leaving your function, at which point that area of the stack is freed and used by other parts of your application.

You will either need to allocate memory on the heap for the string or you will need to pass in the storage from the calling function.

Since you are already doing string manipulation, using std::string to encapsulate-away the management overheads would be most logical. Take a reference to a standard string as an argument:

```
void getDirListing(std::string& msg) {
}
```

and then call with

```
std::string dirListing = "";
getDirListing(dirListing);
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines look suspicious:

```
string lastmod(lm);
lastmod.at(lastmod.size()-1) = '\0';
```

Inserting a null char into the middle of a string class instance is probably generating unexpected behavior (such as premature termination of your string when printed).

I don't think you need to do this.  Just try removing the `lastmod.at` line.